# Use TFS API to send the email notification on MTM test case failure

Tags: tfs, mtm

I want to trigger the email notification to certain group of people whenever any test case in MTM fails.

how to write TFS API to achieve the same? is there any solution already available.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Clarify the question. You want sample code to create an Alert?

Comment: @GiulioVian: yes, whenever the test cases fails , a email notification must be sent to predefined group of people with test case failure reason.

Comment: Ankit, my question is (long version). Are you looking for: how to write an MTM plugin, how to manually create a (server side) TFS Alert monitoring Test Result and then the code to create the Alert automatically or what?

Comment: @GiulioVian, I am looking for code to monitor TFS test result!

Answer (score 0):

When a Test Case failed your Tester should create a Bug with the details of the test failure. You can then have an alert on the creation and update of Bugs.

If it is an automated test as part of a build you can email the tester on build failure so they can create a bug.

If it is an automated test as part of Release Management you can get RM to email the validator (could be the tester) to create the bugs.